# Tomcat not starting in eclipse - no timeout issue - PFB logs

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8.5

Tomcat starting from command prompt but not from eclipse.
No problem shown in logs. logs shows server started successfully.
Tomcat staring from command prompt but not from eclipse.
No problem shown in logs. logs shows server started successfully.

```
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:spring-interceptor' did not find a matching property.
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\FILES\Softwares\NewACFEclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\FILES\Softwares\NewACFEclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\jre\bin\client;C:\oms\bb\cord9software\ant\bin;O:\ora1106w\BIN;C:\PROGRA~2\CA\SC\etpki\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin;c:\progra~1\ca\sc\etpki\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\AmdocsProcessManager\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files\provision networks\virtual access client\;c:\oms\hotdeployment;C:\Bea10.3.4\wlserver_10.3;C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\Cryptography\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SCM;O:\ora11202w\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\GnuWin32\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\Users\akashmu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\FILES\Softwares\NewACFEclipse;;.]
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1216 ms
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:19 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 23, 2019 1:53:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11105 ms
```

Comment: What should be working that isn't working? How do you *know* it failed to start? What symptom are you seeing?

Comment: http://localhost:8080 not opening server dashboard

Answer (score 0):

If you are staring the Tomcat server from the Java app then make sure it is attached to the app. Otherwise, start the server independently and the console logs will print the error if any.